# Flickering with .searchable List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

For the example, you need to add [LoremSwiftum](https://github.com/lukaskubanek/LoremSwiftum) with SPM.

I'm found that when using the [.init(_:id:rowContent:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/list/init(_:id:rowcontent:)-4s0aj) constructor of List, there is flickering of the row items in the search field.

[Video of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LkISm.jpg)

```
import SwiftUI
import LoremSwiftum

let words = Array(Set(Lorem.words(3000).components(separatedBy: " ")))

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var searchText = ""
    
    var searchedWords: [String] {
        searchText.isEmpty ? words : Array(words.filter { $0.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchText) }.prefix(50))
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(searchedWords, id:\.self) { word in
                HStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 50, height: 50).foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text(word)
                }

            }
            .searchable(text: $searchText, placement: .navigationBarDrawer(displayMode: .always))
        }
       
    }
}
```

Using .indices makes the flicker go away, ie:

```
List(searchedWords.indices, id:\.self) { i in
     let word = words[I]
     ...
}
```

although as I understand it, using .indices can cause problems when the items change.

Using `.id(UUID())` on the List also makes the flickering go away, although this has some problems as well.

So, how can I use the correct constructor of List and not have awful flickering of the items when searching?

Comment: Found any solution? I'm using UUID, still issue persists

Answer (score 0):

Try avoiding computed properties for lists identifiable at least.
I had next object for list item:

```swift
struct Message: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable {
    var id: String { UUID().uuidString }
    let title: String
    let message: String
}
```

It was flickering very similar to your example.
Changing structure to next one solved issue for me.

```swift
struct Message: Identifiable, Equatable, Codable {
    
    let id: String
    let title: String
    let message: String
    
    init(title: String, message: String) {
        self.id = UUID().uuidString
        self.title = title
        self.message = message
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using the following code and I don't experience the flicker.

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var words = Array(Set(Lorem.words(3000).components(separatedBy: " ")))
    @State private var searchText: String = ""
    @State private var filteredWords: [String] = []

    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
        
            List(filteredWords, id: \.self) { word in
                HStack {
                    Rectangle().frame(width: 50, height: 50).foregroundColor(.red)
                    Text(word)
                }
            }.searchable(text: $searchText)
                .onChange(of: searchText) { search in
                    filteredWords = words.filter({ $0.starts(with: search.lowercased())})
                }
                .onAppear {
                    filteredWords = words
                }
        }
    }
}
```